# USB camera not working

Tags: camera

I plugged a USB HD camera on my computer (O.S. Ubuntu) and it is working with very low quality (not HD) while the same camera I used it on windows and it was HD.

I am surprised why in ubuntu the camera quality is bad with no colors. Should I have to install the camera software ???

please advise...

Comment: Hani, please provide more details - model of your camera, graphics card, version of your Ubuntu.

Comment: Also show us: Unplug camera. Wait 15 Sec. Plug in camera. Type `dmesg -T`

Answer (score 0):

You may have to adjust the resolution or something. For a really basic but capable webcam app, there is guvcview.

Guvcview has more options than more common apps like "cheese". Also, there is a viriety of video formats to choose from which may attribute to the difference in quality you mentioned in your post (I believe there are even ms video formats are available).

You can install it through the Ubuntu software center or you can run the following commands to install it right now:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```